# Lowest value from 2 payloads in Node-Red

Tags: mqtt, node-red, domoticz

I have a IoT system in home and two temperature sensors. 
One of the sensors could work in some hours in direct sun.
The real temperature is always the **lowest value**, so sometimes temp1, sometimes temp2.

What I want to achieve is:

1. read the temperature from sensors1 (via MQTT)
2. read the temperature from sensors2 (via MQTT)
3. compare values
4. find the lowest one and send in via MQTT
5. go back to reading in loop

For this example I can simulate readings with injection nodes

How to do that? I am new in Node-Red, have tried but without success.

Here is my flow:

```
[{"id":"fa6372cc.47f92","type":"tab","label":"Flow 8","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"5ac90e03.22da3","type":"join","z":"fa6372cc.47f92","name":"","mode":"custom","build":"object","property":"payload","propertyType":"msg","key":"topic","joiner":"","joinerType":"str","accumulate":true,"timeout":"","count":"2","reduceRight":false,"reduceExp":"","reduceInit":"","reduceInitType":"","reduceFixup":"","x":990,"y":340,"wires":[["f09774bf.3c8428","a197b84d.6a7338"]]},{"id":"f09774bf.3c8428","type":"debug","z":"fa6372cc.47f92","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","x":1130,"y":340,"wires":[]},{"id":"43900e79.98cd8","type":"change","z":"fa6372cc.47f92","name":"set payload value","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"req.params.value","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":790,"y":340,"wires":[["5ac90e03.22da3"]]},{"id":"b71d9143.c03bd","type":"change","z":"fa6372cc.47f92","name":"set topic temp1","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"topic","pt":"msg","to":"temp1","tot":"str"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":560,"y":320,"wires":[["43900e79.98cd8"]]},{"id":"e87114aa.6cd1","type":"change","z":"fa6372cc.47f92","name":"set topic temp2","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"topic","pt":"msg","to":"temp2","tot":"str"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":560,"y":360,"wires":[["43900e79.98cd8"]]},{"id":"783c47fd.8dd58","type":"inject","z":"fa6372cc.47f92","name":"temp source 2","topic":"","payload":"12","payloadType":"num","repeat":"3","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":"1.5","x":380,"y":360,"wires":[["e87114aa.6cd1"]]},{"id":"271dedab.aaa7b2","type":"inject","z":"fa6372cc.47f92","name":"temp source 1","topic":"","payload":"10","payloadType":"num","repeat":"2","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":"1","x":380,"y":320,"wires":[["b71d9143.c03bd"]]},{"id":"a197b84d.6a7338","type":"mqtt out","z":"fa6372cc.47f92","name":"temperature","topic":"domoticz/in","qos":"","retain":"","broker":"7e3561ec.acad","x":1150,"y":280,"wires":[]},{"id":"7e3561ec.acad","type":"mqtt-broker","z":"","name":"Domoticz","broker":"192.168.6.11","port":"8084","clientid":"","usetls":false,"compatmode":true,"keepalive":"60","cleansession":true,"birthTopic":"","birthQos":"0","birthRetain":"false","birthPayload":"","closeTopic":"","closeRetain":"false","closePayload":"","willTopic":"","willQos":"0","willRetain":"false","willPayload":""}]
```

Comment: Have a look at the Node-RED context https://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions#storing-data

Comment: Hello hardillb, yes I've seen this article however still can't get it to work. Can you help with this case?

Comment: Then edit the question to show what you've tried (e.g. contents of function node rather than just dumping a whole flow that we need to import to look at)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be like this:

[image]

This is storing the two temps in flow variables - the first flow initially sets them to a high number so the "min" in "choose lower value" will later work. In this case I've used a `change node` setting the payload to the JSONata of

```
$min([$flowContext("temp1"), $flowContext("temp2")])
```

but there's a few ways you could choose to do it.

Here is the code to try:

```
[{"id":"6bc2755e.9feb9c","type":"debug","z":"f454a93f.0e89d8","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","x":990,"y":340,"wires":[]},{"id":"38bd03eb.f7d06c","type":"change","z":"f454a93f.0e89d8","name":"choose lower value","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"$min([$flowContext(\"temp1\"), $flowContext(\"temp2\")])\t","tot":"jsonata"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":790,"y":340,"wires":[["6bc2755e.9feb9c"]]},{"id":"9066677f.eb0358","type":"change","z":"f454a93f.0e89d8","name":"store temp1","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"temp1","pt":"flow","to":"payload","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":550,"y":320,"wires":[["38bd03eb.f7d06c"]]},{"id":"a70c9b2a.e7db58","type":"change","z":"f454a93f.0e89d8","name":"store temp2","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"temp2","pt":"flow","to":"payload","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":550,"y":360,"wires":[["38bd03eb.f7d06c"]]},{"id":"4bd27616.d022c8","type":"inject","z":"f454a93f.0e89d8","name":"temp source 2","topic":"","payload":"12","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":"1.5","x":370,"y":360,"wires":[["a70c9b2a.e7db58"]]},{"id":"7378dd4f.3825b4","type":"inject","z":"f454a93f.0e89d8","name":"temp source 1","topic":"","payload":"10","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":"1","x":370,"y":320,"wires":[["9066677f.eb0358"]]},{"id":"314eb0ec.85211","type":"inject","z":"f454a93f.0e89d8","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":true,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":370,"y":260,"wires":[["688646b.138a6b8"]]},{"id":"688646b.138a6b8","type":"change","z":"f454a93f.0e89d8","name":"set to high","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"temp1","pt":"flow","to":"999","tot":"num"},{"t":"set","p":"temp2","pt":"flow","to":"999","tot":"num"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":550,"y":260,"wires":[[]]}]
```